# Convert int to sbyte in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, type-conversion, byte, sbyte

I recently bought some Bluetooth LE Devices and wanted to read the Data coming from them in Unity. The Problem is I used a library that gives me only a byte array. But I need a sbyte Array.

Example output: 
`83,186,1,3`
But I want:
 `38, -70,1,3`

Here is my Code:

```cs
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
z = 0;

result = Convert.ToString(bytes[3], 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
Debug.Log("First Conversion:" + result.Remove(0,1) + " Original:" + bytes[3]);
sbyte result1 = sbyte.Parse(result.Remove(0,1));
Debug.Log("Conversion:" + result1 + " Original:" + bytes[3]);
```

I've tried this for the last 5h. The farthest I've got was an error that said that my number was too small or too large.

Comment: What is `bytes`? Why are you converting data to a string and then parsing? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Assuming that `bytes` is an array of bytes that you want to convert to `sbyte`, you can do `unchecked { sbyte[] sbytes = bytes.Select(b => (sbyte)b).ToArray(); }`

Comment: why does your snippet contain unused variables x,y and z? please only provide relevant stuff if you're asking for help. how  does 83 become 38 by converting it to sbyte? I guess this is a typo... your title asks how to convert int to sbyte while your post asks how to convert a byte array to a sbyte array. come on!

Answer (score 2):

#### There is an easy method of conversion, you can use:

```
sbyte[] signed = (sbyte[]) (Array) unsigned;
```

It works due to byte and sbyte having the same length in memory. They can be converted without the need to change memory representation.

---

#### However,

the method above might lead to bugs and weird behaviour with the debugger. If the byte array is not that big, you could use `Array.ConvertAll` instead.

```
sbyte[] signed = Array.ConvertAll(unsigned, b => unchecked((sbyte)b));
```